# Are there any negative health effects associated with breathing in air surrounding sulphur hot springs?

Tags: lasting-effects-duration, breathing, environmental-climate, toxicology, sulphur

Are there any negative health effects associated with breathing in air surrounding sulphur hot springs?

I would be interested in what sort of gaseous compounds might be found in such air, which might likely have a negative health-wise impact.

Comment: Does the spring emit toxic hydrogen sulfide? It smells like rotten eggs and can overcome a person quickly. But not all springs emit it.

Comment: @MikeWaters Is a smell of *sulphur* due to the hot springs enough to deduce that *hydrogen sulfide* is being emitted? I am just asking about general sulphur hot springs though.